# Is it possible to access implementation's vtbl?

Tags: c++

I'm reading Scott Myerses C++ and he said that ussually when we make a member function virtual our class will contain a pointer to a so called vtable in additional to its members. So, is it possible to acces this poiter somehow? I undersand that it's implementation details but neverthless maybe we can do it with g++ or clang.

Comment: Yeah, use your debugger to figure out where it is (somewhere between `&x` and `&x + 1`)

Comment: Try running your program in a debugger, at least some display a `__vtbl` member. If not, a good assumption is that the object's layout is so that the vtable comes first.

Comment: @MattMcNabb In particularly, in gdb how can I acquire the size of the vtbl and its implementation details.

Comment: Look in the object's storage area for bytes that look like a pointer, check the memory where that pointer points to see if it contains other code addresses. If you call a virtual function and step through the call this will show you what you're looking for.  Its size probably isn't stored anywhere so you'll have to guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simple way to explore this is with http://gcc.godbolt.org - which lets you type in a program and see the GCC-generated x86 assembly (alternatively, try `-S` or `/S` (VC++) with your own compiler).  I put this program in:

```
struct X
{
    virtual ~X() { }
    virtual void f() { }
};

int main()
{
  X x;
}
```

Clicked "Directives" so it showed the vtable information as follows...

```
.LFE5:
    .size   main, .-main
    .weak   vtable for X
    .section    .rodata._ZTV1X,"aG",@progbits,vtable for X,comdat
    .align 32
    .type   vtable for X, @object
    .size   vtable for X, 40
vtable for X:
    .quad   0
    .quad   typeinfo for X
    .quad   X::~X()
    .quad   X::~X()
    .quad   X::f()
    .weak   typeinfo name for X
    .section    .rodata._ZTS1X,"aG",@progbits,typeinfo name for X,comdat
    .type   typeinfo name for X, @object
    .size   typeinfo name for X, 3
typeinfo name for X:
    .string "1X"
    .weak   typeinfo for X
    .section    .rodata._ZTI1X,"aG",@progbits,typeinfo for X,comdat
    .align 16
    .type   typeinfo for X, @object
    .size   typeinfo for X, 16
typeinfo for X:
    .quad   vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info+16
    .quad   typeinfo name for X
    .text
```